# Line range in sed matches multiple times in a file

Tags: sed

Suppose I have a file `my_file`:

```
start
startx
start3
hi
start4
end
done
stop
endagain
```

And now I try `sed -n '/start/,/end/p' < my_file`.  How will `sed` interpret this range of lines since `start` occurs 4 times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As running your command against your sample input will show you, the *first* line that contains `start` through the *nearest following* line that contains `end` (inclusively), will match.

`sed` doesn't support overlapping ranges:

- Once the start pattern on a range matches a line, looking for the end of the range will start on the *next* line[1], and no matching of the *start* pattern will occur until *after* the end of the range is found.
- The range ends once either the end pattern is matched or the end of the input is encountered.

Looking for the *next* range then starts on the line *after* the one that ended the previous one.

<sup>Note that I use the term "line" loosely here: while it's the default case to operate on lines, in `sed` terms it should be called *pattern space*, which *can* be something other than a line, depending on how the commands in the script manipulate the lines read.</sup>

[1] Note that, by contrast, `awk` starts looking for the end pattern on the *same* line (record).